# Spring MVC Exceptions

Tags: exception, spring-mvc, error-handling

I have the following code in the **Controller** class and for some reason although i have exception handling implemented as well as a **try.....catch** block i am still unable to capture my exceptions.

I am just executing a test, in the **DAO** class i change the sql string that inserts into the database to leave out a column just so the **DAO** will fail. The **DAO** class fails and the error is written to the logs however even thou the **officerManager.RegisterOfficer(officer)** was not successful the code goes on to return the **model.addAttribute("results","Record Was Saved").**

This is not accurate and i would like for the controller to throw an error. Under is the code.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="officer_registration.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleRequest(@Valid @ModelAttribute Officers officer,BindingResult result,ModelMap m,Model model,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception{

         try{
             if(result.hasErrors()){

                 model.addAttribute("division", myDivision);
                 model.addAttribute("position", myPosition);
                 model.addAttribute("gender", myGender);
                 return new ModelAndView("officer_registration");

            }else{

                //check the request if its an update or an insert
                String user_request = request.getParameter("user_request");
                logger.info("The Users Request Was " + user_request);

                if (user_request.equals("Save")){

                        officerManager.RegisterOfficer(officer);
                        model.addAttribute("results","Record Was Saved");

                }else{

                    officerManager.UpdateOfficer(officer);
                    model.addAttribute("results","Record Was Updated");
                }

                 model.addAttribute("division", myDivision);
                 model.addAttribute("position", myPosition);
                 model.addAttribute("gender", myGender);            
                return new ModelAndView("officer_registration");
            }   


         }catch(Exception e ){
             model.addAttribute("division", myDivision);
             model.addAttribute("position", myPosition);
             model.addAttribute("gender", myGender);
             model.addAttribute("results","Error: Unable to Save Record!");
             return new ModelAndView("officer_registration");
         }



     }
```

**DAO**

```
public void saveOfficer(Officers officer) {
    logger.info("In saveOfficer");


    //SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try{

        int count = getJdbcTemplate().update("INSERT INTO crimetrack.tblofficers (userName,password, fName, lName, oName, divisionNo, positionId, emailAdd, startDate, endDate, genderId,phoneNo, dob,badgeNo) "+
                                            "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
                                            , new Object[]{officer.getUserName(),StringSecurity.EncryptString(officer.getPassword()),officer.getfName(),
                                             officer.getlName(),officer.getoName(),officer.getDivisionNo(),officer.getPositionId(),
                                             officer.getEmailAdd(),officer.getStartDate(),officer.getEndDate(),officer.getGenderId(),
                                             officer.getPhoneNo(),officer.getDob(),officer.getBadgeNo()});

    logger.info(count +" Rows affected in tblOfficers");



    }catch(Exception e){

        logger.error("Could not save officer ", e);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowing the error to bubble up back to the controller.

You're handling the exception within the DAO, in which case the method exits normally, and no exception is caught within the Controller.

Either don't surround the DAO with a try catch and let the exception bubble back to the controller (recommended), or catch and rethrow the exception (if you follow this route, throw as a RuntimeException, either create your own, or rethrow as a RuntimeException, that way you won't have to catch all the way through the call stack.)

Also, it's generally frowned upon to catch generic exception as it is tougher to nail down exactly what caused it unless you look within the logs.  Knowing which exceptions to handle ahead of time is usually better practice.